# UDP Client Receive only working when a local sender is used

Tags: c#, networking, udp, udpclient

I'm using `UdpClient` to grab UDP datagrams from Forza, a car racing game using their built in *data out* function.
I've set the data out target endpoint on Forza to be 127.0.0.1:5300
[image: udp packets being sent]

I can verify that these are being sent, and in fact are able to be received by my application.

[image: packets received]

The problem is that they are **only** received after adding an internal heartbeat.

```cs
       public const int FORZA_DATA_OUT_PORT = 5300;
       public const int FORZA_HOST_PORT = 5200;

       private static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, FORZA_DATA_OUT_PORT);            
           var senderClient = new UdpClient(FORZA_HOST_PORT);

           // Heartbeat task - remove this and nothing is received
           var senderTask = Task.Run(async () =>
           {
               while (true)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("Sending heartbeat");
                   await senderClient.SendAsync(new byte[1], 1, ipEndPoint);
                   await Task.Delay(5000);

               }
           });

           int count = 0;
           var receiverTask = Task.Run(async () =>
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Packet Forwarding UP!");
               var client = new UdpClient(FORZA_DATA_OUT_PORT);
               Console.WriteLine("Listening... ");
               while (true)
               {
                   var receive = await client.ReceiveAsync();
                   count++;
                   Console.WriteLine($"{count:D5} - {receive.Buffer.Length}B - {receive.RemoteEndPoint.Address} - {receive.RemoteEndPoint.AddressFamily} - {receive.RemoteEndPoint.Port}");
               }
           });

          Task.WaitAll(senderTask, receiverTask);
       }
```

If I remove the `senderClient.SendAsync` then no packets are received.
Packets are being detected by the LiveTcpUdpWatch program both with and without the line.

Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Some Servers automatically start sending data when started and other server you need a command before the server will start sending.  For example is you had a scale that measured weights.  There are three options 1) The scale starts sending data continuously when started.  2) The scales waits for a configuration command before sending data continuously 3) The scale only makes a measurement when a command is sent (not continuously).  So you racing game looks like you need to send a command before getting a response.

Comment: @jdweng Reasonable assumption, but not sure that's the case here. Packets are being received by the `LiveTcpUdpWatch` before I try start my app, and are only received after the heartbeat call.

Comment: Try changing listening IP From IPAddress.Loopback to IPAddress.IPAny.  It is better to use IPAny than Loopback in this case.  Then change from : new UdpClient(FORZA_HOST_PORT); To : new UdpClient(ipEndPoint);  My best guess is the endpoint is getting setup differently with the Send code.

Comment: If I change UdpClient(FORZA_HOST_PORT) to  UdpClient(ipEndPoint) I get an exception about bindings as the game has already bound to that port. If I remove FORZA_HOST_PORT from the instantiation, the messages are not received.

Comment: Why are you opening the same port twice?  The port is already open so in the Receive method you do not have to open again.  Remove the statement var client = new UdpClient(FORZA_DATA_OUT_PORT); in the receive method.

Comment: @jdweng Honestly I don't want to, but this seems to be the only way to get this to work. It's really bizzare.

Comment: I don't seen why you can't use one client for both transmit and receive.  Change the senderClient to client and remove the duplicate in the receive method.

Comment: If I remove either of the clients, the example doesn't work anymore. Here's two of the versions I've tried  https://gist.github.com/deeja/65637b0697e48c1650e7f1a4baa47f06

They print Listening... Sending heartbeat Sending heartbeat

Comment: Also, I totally understand that I should be able to remove one of them. I just don't know why I can't. There is definitely something going on in the background that is preventing me from receiving messages that is "removed" when I use the second client.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to go through the loopback address.  It may have to do with a broadcast message.  You should be able to replace loopback with IPAny.  The only reason I can see issue is a port being blocked or the Port Number already being used.  So I would from cmd.exe >NetStat -a and check if the port is being used.